# TemplateModelException: ?left_pad(...) argument #2 can't be a 0-length string

Tags: freemarker

Kindly help on this error. This was thrown from Freemarker Template.
Here is the StackTrace....

```html
----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${t.file_sequence_number?left_pad(6, ...  [in template "abcdTemplate.ftlh" in macro "FRFC10" at line 13, column 122]
    - Reached through: @FRFC10  [in template "abcdTemplate.ftlh" at line 31, column 1]
Caused by: freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: ?left_pad(...) argument #2 can't be a 0-length string. 
----
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you called the `left_pad` builtin with two parameters, and that the second argument is an empty string.

The second parameter specifies which string is used for padding instead of space characters.

The correct way to use `left_pad` should be:

```
|${"a"?left_pad(10)}|
|${"a"?left_pad(10, "*")}|
```

Output

```
|         a|
|*********a|
```